# The empty slots in the list don't get deleted with TrimExcess()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a Unity game where with a higher score multiplier, more monkeys appear on screen. I am currently using a list to store the Monke GameObject as they get Instantiated and when the score multiplier gets lowered to the default value of 1 all the monkeys except 1 get deleted. As I was testing I discovered that after the deletion of the other monkeys, the Count() method of the list gives back a value of 4, as if the monkeys wheren't deleted or as if it was counting the "empty spaces" in the list as elements. I saw online that the TrimExcess() method should get rid of this excess in order to count the exact number of GameObjects present in the list but as now it doesn't do anything in my code.

Here's the code:

public class DanceManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public static DanceManager Instance;

```
public GameObject monkePrefabSx, monkePrefabDx;

public GameObject chimp1, chimp2, orangutan1, orangutan2, gorilla1, gorilla2;
private List<GameObject> monkes = new List<GameObject>();


void Start()
{
    Instance = this;
    GameObject monke1 = Instantiate(monkePrefabSx);
    monkes.Add(monke1);
}

void Update()
{
    monkes.TrimExcess();
    MonkesUpdate();
    Debug.Log(monkes.Count);
}


void MonkesUpdate()
{

    if (ScoreManager.baseMultiplier * ScoreManager.scoreMultiplier > 1)
    {
        if (ScoreManager.baseMultiplier * ScoreManager.scoreMultiplier == 2 && monkes.Count == 1)
        {
            Debug.Log((ScoreManager.baseMultiplier * ScoreManager.scoreMultiplier) + " " + monkes.Count);
            GameObject newMonke = Instantiate(monkePrefabDx);
            monkes.Add(newMonke);
        }
        if (ScoreManager.baseMultiplier * ScoreManager.scoreMultiplier == 3 && monkes.Count == 2)
        {
            Debug.Log((ScoreManager.baseMultiplier * ScoreManager.scoreMultiplier) + " " + monkes.Count);
            GameObject newMonke = Instantiate(monkePrefabSx);
            monkes.Add(newMonke);
        }
        if (ScoreManager.baseMultiplier * ScoreManager.scoreMultiplier == 4 && monkes.Count == 3)
        {
            Debug.Log((ScoreManager.baseMultiplier * ScoreManager.scoreMultiplier) + " " + monkes.Count);
            GameObject newMonke = Instantiate(monkePrefabDx);
            monkes.Add(newMonke);
        }
    }

else if (monkes.Count != 1)
    {
        int monkesNumber = monkes.Count;
        destroyMonkes(monkesNumber);
    }
    
}

public void destroyMonkes(int count)
{
    int i = count - 1;
    while (i != 0)
    {
        Destroy(monkes[i].gameObject);
        i--;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: _[TrimExcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.trimexcess?view=net-7.0): Sets the capacity to the actual number of elements in the List<T>, if that number is less than a threshold value._

Comment: You may destroy the game object but you arent removing the reference from the list.

Comment: @PavlosMavris no, if you remove items from the list the current `Count` is decreased and the next item is always appended at the end of the list (so basically at index `list.Count`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned `TrimExcess`

> Sets the capacity to the actual number of elements in the List, if that number is less than a threshold value.

Note that

- Capacity: The amount of items the list can maximum hold before it internally needs to grow and reallocate more space
- Count: The actual current amount of items in the list

As was also mentioned the main issue is that you are never removing items from the list, you only call `Destroy` on them.

You want to do e.g.

```
public void destroyMonkes(int count)
{
    var removeAmount = Mathf.Min(count, monkes.Count);

    for(int i = 0; i < removeAmount; i++)
    {
        Destroy(monkes[i].gameObject);
    }

    monkes.RemoveRange(0, removeAmount);
}
```

Though if you anyway always want to remove them all you could also simply do

```
public void destroyAllMonkes(i)
{
    foreach(var monkey in monkes)
    {
        Destroy(monkey.gameObject);
    }

    monkes.Clear();
}
```